# About primitive roots and ways of expressing them.

Tags: congruences, primitive-roots

If $q$ is a primitive root mod $p$ and $q = (2^a)(3^b)(5^c)\pmod p$ for some $a,b,c$ all elements of integers then say that this $q$ has the 'form' $\{2,3,5\}(p)$. Then is it true all the residues $\pmod p$  have this ${2,3,5}(p)$ form given at least one of them, a primitive root, is in this form?

Comment: If $q \equiv 2^a3^b5^c \pmod{p}$ is a primitive root, then by definition every residue $\mod{p}$, and in particular any primitive root, is in the form $r \equiv q^n \equiv 2^{na}3^{nb}5^{nc} \pmod{p}$. I can't tell if this answers what you are asking.

Comment: q = 2^a.3^b.5^c mod(p) for some integers a,b,c . Only as a short form for this I'm labelling this form as {2,3,5}(p) which is supposed to stand for the exponential form used in the congruence.

Comment: @Jimmy K4542 ; yes this what I'm asking. Going further if Q is a primitive root mod p and Q is not in the form {2,3,5}(p) then none of the primitive roots are in this {2,3,5}(p) form. Is this true?